# how to segregate this css into appropriate and unique class so that they do not interfere with other page layouts

Tags: html, css

I am working on a page where I have to show a scrollable table. Please find it in the below jssfiddle link :

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q1avq7f/)

Problem is the actual page where I am including the above html table and the associated css, that page itself has other layout on it and a different css file for that.

I guess my above css file table , td and body is interfering with the other css used in that page and 
destroying the display, Can anybody please help me to change the css in the jssfiddle link above 
so that everything is put into unique class/id and used appropriately in the html. So that no matter how are the remaining page layout , other widgets and layout do not overlap with my table.

My table should remain intact in terms of its look and feel and scroll property.
Apologies, I am not an expert of HTML/CSS

Even if someone can explain me what is the purpose of the first 4 lines 
`* { }` and then 
`body { }`, 
`table { }` , 
`td { }` , will be great help. I think those should put under appropriate class and then used in the html. Please provide some guidelines how can I do that.

Thanks

Comment: Either choose to learn the subject, or hire a developer.  This isn't a "do it for me" site.

Comment: the lines just configure standard values for those element tags.

Comment: and, you can add an id like id="CustomTable" (to your table) and #CustomTable to each of the tags in the css of the table...

Answer (score 0):

```
*{}
```

Applies to every element on the page.  You still want what is there, but you want it to only apply to every element within your scrolling tables, so I changed it to :

```
#scrollTableContainer *{}
```

I move'd your body's font declaration into `div#scrollTableContainer`

And then I prefixed your `table{}`, `td{}`, `td:first-child{}`, `td:first-child + td + td`, `td:first-child + td + td + td` and `td:first-child + td + td + td + td` with the `#scrollTableContainer` ID.

The one thing I didn't decide for you was what to do with your `font-size` in `html{}`.  I am guessing you will still want that.  My suggestion would be to decide on a font size and merge it with the declairation in `div#scrollTableContainer`

**And here is the result :** http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/6q1avq7f/1/